# Why doesn't this image sprite menu display properly, and why aren't the links working?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, html-lists, sprite

The code validates. There should be two more images in the menu on the left, above the visible one of the silo. And each should be a link.

http://www.briligg.com/agnosticism.html

css is:  external style sheet:

```
.menu {
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 10px;
padding: 0;
width: 150px;
}
.menu li {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 260px;
}
.menu li, .menu a {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
}
```

internal style sheet:

```
.menu {
    height: 450px;
}
.mirror {
    top: 0;
}
.mirror {
    background: url(http://www.briligg.com/images/menu-ag.png) 0 0;
}
.wormcan {
    top: 151px;
}
.wormcan {
    background: url(http://www.briligg.com/images/menu-ag.png) 0 -151px;
}
.wormsilo {
    top: 301px;
}
.wormsilo {
    background: url(http://www.briligg.com/images/menu-ag.png) 0 -301px;
}
```

html:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="mirror">
        <a href="whoryou.html"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="wormcan">
        <a href="aroundyou.html"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="wormsilo">
        <a href="beyondyou.html"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum - maybe you should try setting the links (.menu a) to `display: block` to have the links working properly. Otherwise the link won't stretch to use the specified size, links are inline elements (correct me if I'm wrong, didn't test it).

Comment: Yes! that did it, together with what D.A. advised below.

Answer (score 1):

In your internal stylesheet, you have to specify better. Because `.menu li` is very specified, it overruns `.wormcan`.

Try `.menu li.wormcan` in the internal stylesheet.

Haven't tested this, but from a quick look, this seems to be the problem.

Comment: @briligg, With a tool like http://getfirebug.com/ in Firefox, you can easily inspect an element and see in what order the css is added.

Comment: i'm not sure i understood you correctly, but i '.menu li' as a second selector to .mirror, .wormcan, and .wormsilo.

when i did that, all the graphics disappeared.

but that reminded me that on a similar page, these selectors were id's, not classes.  So i tried #mirror, #wormcan, #wormsilo. But the graphics continue to be invisible.

if it's any help, the firebug error console says 
Selector expected. Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
for line 63, which is the end of the ul.

Comment: Wait -
i hadn't changed the html from class= to id=.  woops.  the graphics now display correctly, but the links don't work. 
Now to try the advice of dhh

Comment: i can only give one accepted answer, although i needed the advice from both of you.  I'm giving it to dhh because he has fewer points, and i needed to tweak yours for it to work for me. Sorry!